# Is it possible to flush a single file via http request on apache/modpagespeed?

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

I know it is possible to flush all cache, or to set single file expirations, but I'm curious to know if there's some way to flush a single file via http request;
something like `curl -X DELETE www.example.com/js/a_cached_example.js`.
Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do that in 1.8, but it will be possible in 1.9 or from a trunk build, as of https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/source/detail?r=4069

It will work pretty much exactly as you predicted if you set the request-method to DELETE in the conf file, though PURGE is what we thought was more common.  You will also be able to do that from the admin console (/pagespeed_admin).